# How can I set up Spring Boot app so that folks can access via my IP?

Tags: spring-boot

In JBoss, I just add `-b 0.0.0.0 to the run script`; with that other poeple can access the site via the ip adress.

How can I accomplish the same on Spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use one of the embedded containers you can use the property `server.address=` with your IP (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

Comment: this works! i just needed for dev, so i can show folks stuff without going "hey cmere a minute"